# How to install Github for Windows offline?

Tags: git, github, smartgit

As the question says how to install Github for Windows without an internet connection? 
If it is not possible then is there some alternative client with the following features:

- Support for proxy
- Offline installer

I found smartgit which has an offline installer but it seems it doesn't have proxy support.

If there is no such client then what can be done to extend the functionality of github for windows or some other client? I mean is there a way to use some API to extend it? Any links for that would be helpful.

Comment: SmartGit has Proxy support: make sure you have `http.proxy` and friends properly configured: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html. Note, that SmartGit/Hg's auto-update feature and GitHub 'meta-integration' use separate Proxy settings from the Preferences - Check for New Version. These are completely unrelated to Git operations.

Comment: I have used GitExtensions on Windows, I think the default installation comes with proxy plugin. But seriously, command line is much better than any current client.

Comment: Cannot understand how this is off-topic. FAQ states that SO can be used for questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers". Is Git not used? I was under the impression that it is used.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you. I'll edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: @BoltClock Please see this link if possible. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181461/confusion-regarding-faq-continues

Comment: @AseemBansal I personally prefer Source Tree an intuitive Git UI. Github for windows is meant used for Github.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"GitHub for Windows" is one of those magical/annoying [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) apps. They are ideal for apps that tend to require online to operate (like posting to an online source control website...)

Other then the magic "clone to windows" feature from the website, and the self contained SSH auto-management (also semi-annoying), there isn't anything special about it other then being "pretty".

If you *really really* need offline work, or behind proxies, get something else. GitExtenions is great integration into windows context menus, and a great repo manager, and a not too confusing add/stash/commit interface. It reminds me very much of TortoiseSVN.

MSysgit is also an option for GUIs, but is a bit more crude (it looks very 16bit app'ish). Personally, I'd rather use the commandline then it, but thats me and my choices.

Oh, and lastly, in less then 10 seconds and 1 [google search](http://manku.thimma.org/2012/09/github-for-windows-through-proxies/), I found how to set GHfW to work through a proxy using the standard .gitconfig

Comment: I found the link for making GHfW work through proxy but it is not very good. I took out the proxy when I was using internet without proxy and it broke down. Couldn't log into the software. It said that a proxy was interfering. I made sure that .gitconfig was without the proxy but it didn't work. Will try out GitExtensions and give you feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I checked out GitExtensions. It's working. There is proxy support.

Comment: May be you didn't get the question itself and I'm surprised the author has ticked this answer as responding because the question was "How to INSTALL GitHub for Windows offline or behind a proxy", while you are answering regarding to "How to USE GitHub for Windows offline or behind a proxy".

Anyway, I'm currently in contact with GitHub support and I'll post an answer as soon as I'll get it.

Comment: Hi @RobertoLoGiacco, did you figure it out?

Comment: Actually no, I didn't. I found a very valid alternative into Atlassian SourceTree though, which looks great and has a nice GitHub integration (and it installs in offline mode without problems).

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco I just saw your comment now. At that time I was actually looking for the second thing that you mentioned and I marked this as answer due to that without considering that the wording actually meant something different. I am still using GitExtensions but will take a look at source tree as it is looking nice.

Comment: I wish I had a dollar for every time the GitHub for Windows Clickonce installer failed with "PortableGit.7z, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest."

Answer (score 18):

This is the answer I received from the support today (2015-06-30):

> Unfortunately we do not have a standalone installer at this time.
>   GitHub for Windows makes use of Microsoft's ClickOnce technology for
>   installation and updates.
>
> We are currently working on an open source replacement for ClickOnce
>   here:
>
> https://github.com/squirrel/squirrel.windows
>
> Once that technology is complete and ready for use, we hope to switch
>   GitHub for Windows to use that. It would allow for a standalone
>   installer.
>
> In the meantime, you can find a list of alternate GUIs available
>   here:
>
> http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Answer (score 4):

For the current version (as of June 2017) of GitHub Desktop (windows), you can go to https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/standalone/GitHubDesktop.exe for the standalone, offline installer.

For GitHub Desktop (beta), the team is also working to make it an offline installer hopefully by version 1.0. Currently the installer has some [issues](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/776) that prevent it from installing successfully.