# How can I install Github for Windows offline?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

By now, I can only download a `GitHubSetup.exe` and wait for it to finish downloading the total program.

But my Internet connection is not steady and it would break frequently. Can I get a complete version of Github for Windows so that even if the connection breaks I can still finish installing?

There is a question [How to install Github for Windows offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646205/how-to-install-github-for-windows-offline) in Stack Overflow, but its answer doesn't seem right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Github for Windows offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646205/how-to-install-github-for-windows-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Note: [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) has been rewritten, and [released in Sept. 2017](https://blog.github.com/2017-09-19-announcing-github-desktop-1-0/), almost three years after your question.

I just downloaded (March 2018) its [`GitHubDesktopSetup.exe`](https://central.github.com/deployments/desktop/desktop/latest/win32), and I confirm: the installation process seems offline. Meaning once you have downloaded the 80MB of the setup, you are good to go.